# Server socket on Windows Phone 8 and 8.1

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-8, websocket, windows-phone-8.1, serversocket

I need to port an application to the Windows Phone platform. Is it possible to create server sockets on Windows Phone 8 and 8.1? All I've found is related with client side, like creating connections to remote machines. I can't find nothing the other way: The phone acting as the server.

Any help or confirmation on this will be truly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `StreamSocketListener` class.

Answer (score -1):

It is just an opinion of mine, but when I consider my development experience with the Windows Phone I would say: NO. I don't think MS provide an API for that. Also I can't think about a Windows Phone App which acts as a server. 
Thanks for downvoting without explanantion.
Just to back up my opinion:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202874(v=vs.105).aspx
There it is very clear, that MS thinks about CLIENT sockets when using them.